# Modifying button height dynamically in upward direction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, layoutparams

I'm trying to create graph-like structure using buttons.
 I want to modify the height of these buttons dynamically based on the value of seek bar.

[image: screenshot]

I'm able to implement this as shown in this screen shot 1. But the problem is buttons grows in height in downward direction (which is their default behavior).

---

How do I make buttons grow upward as shown below?
[image: screenshot]

**Xml**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:background="#99f"/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraph2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnGraph"
        android:background="#9f9"/>
```

---

**Activity**

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromTouch) {
    tvValue.setText("Value = " + progress);

 // NEGATIVE HEIGHT WONT WORK HERE...
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
            50, progress * 10));
    lp.setMargins(10, 300, 0, 0);
    btnGraph.setLayoutParams(lp);

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
            50, progress * 5));

    lp.setMargins(100, 300, 0, 0);
    btnGraph2.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Am I doing anything silly? Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is the parent view of the buttons, you could set gravity to bottom if its a linear layout.

Comment: You need to 'redraw' your view. Try to use the `.invalidate();` function on the button. btnGraph2.invalidate();

Comment: I tried `btnGraph.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);` , but it doesn't have any effect...

Comment: After the .setLayoutParams(lp)

Comment: And have you tried it like this: lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            50, progress * 10);

Comment: @Ceetn : `MarginLayoutParams` is the only parameter required by `LayoutParams`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accomplished a bit easier in LinearLayout since there is no relative positions involved. Warp the buttons in a relative layout and control the height of the button using the weight attribute.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sample_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:text="Hello" 
   />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and you can programatically set the weight as follows

```
b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0,count*0.1f));
```

this works for me. The important thing here however is setting the gravity of the LinearLayout (you can also do it programatically).