# different values in onProgressChanged() and onStopTrackingTouch in SeekBar

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-button

I'm dynamically modifying height of the button based on seekbar progress.

Now I want to retreive height of the button. So I used `btn1.getHeight()` in `onProgressChanged()` method of `SeekBar`.
But it gives incorrect/old set of values for button height.

Instead, if I used `btn1.getHeight()` in `onStopTrackingTouch()`, I'm getting correct values.

This simply means , when I try to retreive height of the button in `onProgressChanged()` , UI changes are visible on screen but **yet not registered** wchich results into getting incorrect/old values.

How to get correct values in `onProgressChanged()` ?

Is there other way round to do this? Any help appreciated.

### Edit

@Luksprog : I made following changes :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:maxHeight="9dp"
    android:minHeight="9dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/shine_btn" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Graph01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraph01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#99f" />

    <com.example.calci.views.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGraph01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnGraph01" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Graph02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Graph01"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraph02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#99f" />

    <com.example.calci.views.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGraph02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnGraph02" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and in activity**

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20,
            2 * progress * 1);
    lp2.setMargins(55, 0, 0, 0);
    btnGraph01.setLayoutParams(lp2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(20,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lp3.setMargins(55, 0, 0, 30);
    tvGraph01.setLayoutParams(lp3);
    tvGraph01.setTextSize(6);
    tvGraph01.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

But TextView is getting displayed inside button... Why it is so?

**PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I"M WRONG...**

Comment: My guess is that you modify the `LayoutParams` of your `Button`  in the `onProgressChanged` method. If this is the case what is stopping your from directly using the calculated value for the new height?

Comment: I'm not setting exact height of the button. I'm using weight attribute and hence the height is 0dp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'm guessing this is related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562028/modifying-button-height-dynamically-in-upward-direction). I wouldn't use `weights`, instead I would simply use a `RelativeLayout` with the `Buttons` attached to the bottom, this way the `Buttons` will increase in height upwards. Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:max="200"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#99cc00"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="test" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:background="#0077cc"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second, I don't see why you can't get the desired height. With my code above by using `button.getHeight()` you'll get the previous height store(as the new height will not be stored until you get out of `onProgressChanged`). But this shouldn't stop you from getting the new height because you are actually calculating that value yourself with :

```
progress * 10
```

Code:

```
@Override

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, final int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    LayoutParams lp = findViewById(R.id.button1).getLayoutParams();
                    lp.width = 50;
                    lp.height = progress * 10;
                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setLayoutParams(lp);
                    Log.e("XZX", "Progress : " + progress + " |Old height : "
                            + findViewById(R.id.button1).getHeight()
                            + "  |New height : " + (progress * 10));
                }
```

Edit:
Your layout file is wrong:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Graph01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraph01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#99f" />

    <com.example.calci.views.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGraph01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnGraph01" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in code there is no need to modify the `LayoutParams` of `tvGraph01`, it will follow the `Button` as it grows/shrinks, also get the current `LayoutParams` of the `Button` and modify it instead of creating new ones again and again:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)btnGraph01.getLayoutParams();
lp2.width = 20;
lp2.height = 2 * progress * 1;
lp2.setMargins(55, 0, 0, 0); // <= do you really need the margin? what is its purpose?
btnGraph01.setLayoutParams(lp2);
tvGraph01.setTextSize(6);
```

Comment: I tried relative layout , but then textview is getting displayed inside button. I don't have any idea why it is happening?